# Build Nuclear Device in Civilization 6

Tags: civilization-6

This is a two part question.

1. What are the prerequisites for Building a Nuclear Device ( a nuke )
2. How does one actually go about building a nuke?  Once the prerequisites are met, what menus do I need to go through to actually build a nuke.  Do I need to build it in a specific location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Research the following:

   1. Advanced Ballistics
   2. Combined Arms

[image: Civ6 Tech Tree]

2. Start the Build Nuclear Device Project

   1. Look in your stockpile after it is completed to make sure it is build
   2. Use the military engineer to build a silo or launch it via a bomber

Use this video